# Can I use getResourceAsStream() to read a .gz file ? (on AWS)

Tags: java, stream, inputstream, emr

I am running some MapReduce job on AWS, and I was able to read a .csv file using

```
InputStream fstream = MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream("myPath/myFile.csv");
```

However if `myFile` is in the format of `myFile.csv.gz`, I tried

```
InputStream fstream = MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream("myPath/myFile.csv.gz");
```

and it returns null.

Does any one have any suggestions?

Comment: That's strange; at the very least this should have returned you an `InputStream` with the gzipped contents. Are you sure about the location of the file?